# Difference between "к" and "за" in time expressions?

Tags: выражения

In my grammar textbook under the section of time expressions in the Russian language there is a table presented with various types of constructions per case. Under предложный падеж are listed the expressions "за обедом/завтраком/ужином" whilst under творительный падеж are listed the expressions "к обеду/завтраку/ужину".

I wondered what the difference is between these two constructions? As a non-native speaker the meaning seems identical to me. What nuance can be derived between the following sentences for instance?

"приходите к нам за обедом"
"приходите к нам к обеду"

Comment: The case associated to за in your examples is not предложный, but творительный, and the case associated to к is not творительный, but rather дательный.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meanings are different and not even close.

*(делать что-либо) за обедом/ужином/завтраком* - to do something during that meal (to speak or to watch TV for example).

*(сделать что-либо) к обеду/завтраку/ужину* - to finish doing something by that time.

*Приходите к нам за обедом* - come to us to get the dinner (often implied that you will then go away with the food and not stay with us).

*Приходите к нам к обеду* - come to us to dinner time (just as approximate time, not necessarily to have dinner with us).

Answer (score 3):

"За обедом" is in instrumental case (творительный падеж), not prepositional (предложный). This phrase is most often used as an adverbial and means "во время обеда, обедая" ("during lucn, whilst having lunch").

- За завтраком, между блюд ― встают и танцуют, и в пять часов, и за обедом, и так до утра.
- Он проводил много времени за обедом.

Note that it only applies to the actions of somebody who is actually having a meal. So you can't say for example "За обедом к нам пришли гости". Not in this sense, at least, as this clumsy phrase could be misinterpreted as "guests came to get a lunch from us". To understand why instrumental case is used here, you can think of it this way: somebody did something while he was occupied with lunch, "занят (чем?) обедом". Apart from meals, there are not many activities which can be used in a similar way in a sentence. "За игрой", "за уроком", are a few other examples which come to mind.

Much less frequently, "за обедом" could mean "чтобы получить обед" (in order to get a lunch):

- Я пришла с судками за обедом.

It could also mean "after lunchtime":

- Вслед за обедом наступали ранние декабрьские сумерки.

"К обеду" is in dative case (дательный падеж), not instrumental (творительный). This phrase can be used in the following ways:

- Пригласить к обеду. Invite for dinner.
- Таня проснулась к обеду. Tanya woke up by lunchtime.
- Время близится к обеду. Lunchtime is approaching.
- К обеду была вареная говядина. For lunch, there was  boiled beef.

"Приходите к нам **за обедом**" means "come to us to get your lunch/dinner".
"Приходите к нам **к обеду**" means "come to us by lunch/dinner time".
I guess what you are actually thinking of is "приходите к нам **на обед**", which would be "come to us for dinner".